# Magento: how know your customers

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes, customer

I'd like to know better the customers as people: for example a report that show me how many people are from a specific country or how many people have a specific dog or smartphone ecc... (all the information that i want to retrieve are inserted at sign up also with custom attribute).

There is a method in magento to create such report?

Comment: No, there is no such report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such report and no easy way to achieve this. If you ask me the fastest way might be to export all your customers to CSV, import in Excel and run there the reports.

Or you build your own reports

or you look for an extension where you can do this, but afaik will excel do the job really great (or open office, libre office, numbers...)

Answer (score 0):

Magento doesn't have anything that detailed built in, but you can setup Google Analyticss really easy and integrate it with Magento which does track most everything you are looking for.

Once you have your Google Analytics account setup they will give you some code to plugin to your site.  Just take that and in the System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Google API it asks for your account number.  This auto-generates analytics tracking on every web page for the entire Magento site.

Then you should be able to export/generate reports from Analytics.